# Creating multiple if statements within a loop and printing to a text file

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am trying to create a loop with multiple if,else statements which will then print the results to a text file. I would also like to write two separate categories to the text file, one for 'staff' and one for 'teaching staff'. Is anyone able to assist with making this functional please? A copy of my code is below.

```
staffType = input("Enter 1 for Staff, 2 for Teaching staff or enter 0 to exit: ")
if staffType=='1':
        firstInput = input("Enter first name: ")
        lastInput =input("Enter last name: ")
        depInput = input("Enter department name: ")
        staffType = input("Is a staff or a teacher? ")
elif staffType=='2':
        firstInput = input("Enter first name: ")
        lastInput =input("Enter last name: ")
        depInput = input("Enter department name: ")
        staffType = input("Is a staff or a teacher? ")
        disciplineInput = input("Enter staff member's discipline: ")
        lnInput = input("Enter staff member's license number: ")
if StaffType == "0":
        print("You have exited the program")
        break
        
StaffFile = open("staff.txt", "a")
StaffFile.write('\nThe staff members are:\n' dobInput, firstInput, lastInput, staffType '\n')
StaffFile.write('\nThe teaching staff are:\n' dobInput, firstInput, lastInput, staffType, disciplineInput, lnInput '\n')
StaffFile.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: you're missing the commas inside the `write` statement, before `dobInput` and after `staffType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using only one file to write them on, consider defining a new file to store new inputs to their respective category.

also, you were missing some commas at the `write`

```
    staffType = input("Enter 1 for Staff, 2 for Teaching staff or enter 0 to exit: ")
if staffType=='1':
        firstInput = input("Enter first name: ")
        lastInput =input("Enter last name: ")
        depInput = input("Enter department name: ")
        staffType = input("Is a staff or a teacher? ")
        StaffFile = open("staff.txt", "a")
        StaffFile.write('\nThe staff members are:\n'+ firstInput + s + lastInput + s + staffType + '\n')
        StaffFile.close()
elif staffType=='2':
        firstInput = input("Enter first name: ")
        lastInput =input("Enter last name: ")
        depInput = input("Enter department name: ")
        staffType = input("Is a staff or a teacher? ")
        disciplineInput = input("Enter staff member's discipline: ")
        lnInput = input("Enter staff member's license number: ")
        StaffFile = open("teaching_staff.txt", "a")
        StaffFile.write('\nThe teaching staff are:\n'+ firstInput + s + lastInput + s + staffType + s + disciplineInput + s + lnInput + '\n')
        StaffFile.close()

if StaffType == "0":
        print("You have exited the program")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate the advice!

Comment: I get the error 'break outside loop'. Any thoughts on how to correct that?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, try adding breaks after the closing statements of the Staff files since they don't have any break points, like this for example:

https://onlinegdb.com/S9Gs6q52mw

Comment: No problems and thanks for the help. I did try that code but still receive the same error. I'll continue to have a play around to see if i can resolve the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: after reading your code again, I noticed there were some syntax that are off... the `break outside of loop` only happens when you placed the `break` outside of a loop or placed it on a not loop statement at all. If you don't mind, I made my own version based off to your work that works based from what would you like to happen with the code you provided. https://onlinegdb.com/L7JUUsu42

Comment: in my own version, I defined a new variable named `s` with whitspaces as it's value (the "   " ) just to separate the firstInput,  lastInput and the staffType

Comment: thank you very much. That was very helpful. I just had to put the options 1,2,3 in " " to make it work. Appreciate the help!